# I don't know if my CARET model is classification or regression?

Tags: r, regression, classification

I am using CARET package in R for predictive modelling. I don't know if my model is classification and regression, but whenever I use regression only models, it gives an error.

```
      control <- trainControl(method='repeatedcv', 
                    number=10, 
                    repeats=3,
                    classProbs = T)


     set.seed(1)
     scaled_t$Training=factor(scaled_t$Training)
     knn_grid1 = train(Training~., 
              data=scaled_t,
              method = "knn",
              trControl = control,
              tuneGrid = expand.grid(k = seq(1, 31, by = 2))
    )
    knn_grid1
```

Comment: Can you show the `structure(scaled_t)`? You are making `scaled_t$Training` a factor variable. Under such a situation it will be a classification problem. If your `scaled_t$Training` would have been a continuous variable then only you can fit the regression model.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. When I use my scaled_t$Training in continuous variable, this model gives me such error. And when I convert it to factor variable, it runs perfectly.

Warning messages:

1: In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  You are trying to do regression and your outcome only has two possible values Are you trying to do classification? If so, use a 2 level factor as your outcome column.

2: In train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
  cannnot compute class probabilities for regression

Comment: Can you show `dput(head(scaled_t)` or `structure(scaled_t)`? Your `scaled_t$Training` has only two levels that do not make it a continuous variable. With only 2 possible values you can not run a regression.

Comment: Here is the structure: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VSXafY0LHWk8aa9RbT1jCPvrYVVO4PbM .I want to run a regression but I am only able to run classification models. Regards.

Comment: It can not be a regression model if your dependent variable is `scaled_t$Training` which is having only 2 class. In order to run a regression model, your dependent variable should have different values for almost all the samples/observations.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can I run regression without using Caret then?

Comment: It can not be a regression problem whether you use `caret` or not. It's a case of basics about classification and regression problems not regarding R packages.

Comment: I got it, thank you very much. Now, what could be the difference in using independent variables as a factor variable or as a numeric variable while doing classification? Is it necessary to convert all variables to factor for running classification models?

Comment: Not all the variables but the dependent variable should be a factor to run a classification model for `caret` package.